# Shutdown system (computer) with a ROS node

Tags: ros, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to shutdown the system from within a ROS node?

In my case, I would like to shutdown the system once the battery level reaches a certain point, however I don't know how to do it or if it is even possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214554/shutdown-system-(computer)-with-a-ros-node/) by [nwanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/23134/nwanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to add to the answer by @FooBar (ROS nodes are really just regular Linux programs that have chosen to communicate with each other via the ROS middleware): shutting down a Linux system with a desktop environment is often possible without using something like `shutdown` (which requires special privileges). See "[Linux: Programatically shutdown or reboot computer from a user-level process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774312/linux-programatically-shutdown-or-reboot-computer-from-a-user-level-process)" on stackoverflow for an example where they use ConsoleKit / DBus:

```
dbus-send \
    --system \
    ---dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit \
    --type=method_call \
    --print-reply \
    --reply-timeout=2000 \
    /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
    org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

You could invoke `dbus-send` using the `system(..)` function call in C/C++, or execute it from a Python node.

For Python there are better (more integrated) ways to interface with ConsoleKit / DBus (copied from "[shutting down computer (linux) using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013274/shutting-down-computer-linux-using-python)" on stackoverflow):

```
import dbus
sys_bus = dbus.SystemBus()
ck_srv = sys_bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit',
                            '/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager')
ck_iface = dbus.Interface(ck_srv, 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager')
stop_method = ck_iface.get_dbus_method("Stop")
stop_method()
```

You could fi wrap the call to `stop_method()` (which is just an example) in a ROS service call (I wouldn't use parameters for this, it is clearly a synchronous action).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nwanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/23134/nwanda/) on 2015-09-28**:
This raised another question: Is it possible to close all nodes from within another node? Since this system is controlling some motors I would like to send a command to stop the motors and close all nodes before shutting down.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-29**:
As you already said: this is another question. Please open a new one for that.

**Comment by [nwanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/23134/nwanda/) on 2015-09-29**:
You are totally right. I have already posted a different [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/218412/shutdown-nodes-from-within-a-ros-node/). Thanks for the help!